# Comparing values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using java script to compare values

```
 if (cellValue == "true" || cellValue == true)
```

Instead of doing this can i use the ===operator in java script ?

Comment: Why would you have to compare to `"true"`?

Comment: Have you tried to use it to see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `==` and `===` is that the first one (double equals) does type coercion, which can lead to goofy results:

```
0 == false
true

0 === false
false
```

It is usually recommended to use `===` as that will provide more predictable results and evaluate the true types of the values you're comparing.